# ImportError when running python script

Tags: python

I have a nested python script that imports a module from another directory. When I run the nested python script as:

```
python dir_a/dir_b/script.py
```

It throws an Import Error that it is unable to load the specified module.
However when I run the script as:

```
python -m dir_a.dir_b.script
```

It runs successfully. Any idea why is that?

Comment: In my opinion, importing is the most confusing part about Python.   One of the core developers, Nick Coghlan, wrote this blog post about importing in Python.  Hope it helps. http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

Answer (score 0):

`-m` switch adds the current directory to `sys.path`, which contains the modules that `script.py` imports, while without the `-m` switch `dir_a/dir_b` is added to `sys.path` instead. See python's [command-line documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following,

```
sys.path.insert("relative path of import_module from script.py")

import "import_module"
```